# PHP created ZIP file not working with Windows Explorer

Tags: php, zip

I have the following code which works fine on windows with WinRAR and works fine on Mac's as well. However, for some reason, when you open it with the default windows Explorer, the zip appears empty and when you right click and extract, it says it is invalid. When the same one is opened with winrar or on a mac, all the files are there. Any ideas?

```
$passcode = $_GET['passcode'];

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $download = 'download_files_'.$passcode.'.zip';
    $zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach (glob("../dashboard/uploads/".$passcode."/*.jpg") as $file) { /* Add appropriate path to read content of zip */
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
    header("Location: $download");
```

Comment: Just a tad hard to test this (*but not impossible*) without knowing how it's being used. But I'm suspecting this line `header("Location: $download");` which would basically redirect to (i.e.) `http://www.example.com/download_files_12345.zip` is that the intention? Usually you want a dialog box to pop up and prompt a user to save it; why the redirection?

Comment: Because that's triggering the download when a user clicks a button in my UI. Like i say, it's downloading fine etc, the error is literally that it can't be opened with windows default zip program, but fine on winrar etc

Comment: For example, user clicks a link that is generateZip.php?passcode=123456 and that triggers this code and then downloads it

Comment: Then it's most likely a local issue. I remember answering a similar question once, (a PDF actually) where the OP changed a setting on his computer and BANG!, it worked.

Comment: It's happening on a few client's machines and now my test windows machine. Any ideas on what i can do? lol

Comment: Could be a number of things. I'll see if I can't replicate the problem, but can't make any promises.

Comment: Unbelievable! It was the bloody pathname! I had to move the download file to inside the uploads folder and remove ../dashboard/uploads/. Thank you for talking to me and offering as much advice as you could :)

Comment: Great news and you're welcome.

Comment: Actually what worked for me (while testing) was to change `foreach (glob("images/".$passcode."/*.jpg") as $file)` to `foreach (glob("images/*.jpg") as $file)` without the passcode variable. Yet, it saved the folder's name also and with the `.jpg` files I had inside it. It was saved under the filename `download_files_12345.zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easily fixed by using the following method: I had to move the generate zip file to inside the uploads folder and remove `../dashboard/uploads/` as it was this path that was causing windows to think of it as a corrupt file

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue using following method.

```
foreach (glob("../dashboard/uploads/".$passcode."/*.jpg") as $file) { 
    $zip->addFile(realpath($file), pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: My solution works but i will definitely give this a go soon :)

Comment: Great solution. This will work too if you have the same problem even though you are not including any folders in `$file` (i.e. it's just filename) on a linux server. My linux server was adding "`./`" to the start of the filename, which make Windows Explorer think the zip was empty. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

just my $0.02 - Windows file manager doesn't like, if files in ZIP archives are stored with leading delimiter.

This doesn't work:

```
$zip->addFile(realpath($file), '/mydir/myfile.txt');
```

this works:

```
$zip->addFile(realpath($file), 'mydir/myfile.txt');
```

Comment: This is a better explanation of why my $zip->addFile was working on ubuntu, and dropbox, but failing on windows.  Windows apparently does not like/understand a leading slash in the file path of a zip file, and treats it as a failed/corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

Another one related fix:

Linux is able to read a zip file with some html at the begin, you can use
`ob_clean()` to clear unwanted code sent to the default output.